# Does iPython have built-in support for viewing a variable in pager?

Tags: python, ipython

I often need to view long text variables in iPython. I typically use scroll buffers for this, but I really want a pager with searching. Does iPython have a way to view long variables in a pager (e.g., less)? If not, I can certainly contrive a way to do this with !.

Note: I'm not asking how to set up PAGER generally. ?, ??, %pdoc, etc all work fine with a less. I'm asking specifically for paging variables.

Comment: `IPython.core.page.page(my_string)` :-)

Comment: That's good. I can at least wrap that as a customized function. Do you know of a way to have that invoked by default when displaying a variable?  Something like this:

  `In [1]: import httplib2
  In [2]: resp,data = httplib2.Http().request('http://google.com')
  In [3]: data
  `

Comment: I don't think there's anything built in to IPython to do that, but you can mess with our displayhook implementation. https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/displayhook.py

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740835/how-to-use-pipe-in-ipython. 
This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer: %page

Example usage:

```
snafu$ ipython
In [1]: import httplib2
In [2]: resp,data = httplib2.Http().request('http://google.com')
In [3]: %page data
```

Answer from [How to use Pipe in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740835/how-to-use-pipe-in-ipython)