# Is there a similar thing to Matlab's "more on" in IPython?

Tags: python, matlab, scroll, ipython

I started using IPython. If `more on` is typed in Matlab's Command Window, then Matlab displays the text output one page at a time. [See documentation here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/more.html). If `more off` is typed, then this mode is turned off.

Are there anything similar to this in IPython?

Comment: Thanks, I think that is a similar question but it is not exactly the same. For example, when the following command is executed, print \n.join(sys.modules), I cannot prefix this command by %page.

Comment: Does the answer by [`bstpierre`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5743772/1377097) work for you?